# How to download file through linux expect?

Tags: linux, ssh, expect, scp, socks

I face a trouble about linux expect script. 
I have a computer A which only have LAN connection, while another computer B in the same LAN which have Internet connection. What I want to do is writing a script which can login into computer B through ssh and download file to it and finally use scp to transfer the file to computer A. 
And below is my script.

```
    #!/bin/expect
    set url [lindex $argv 0];
    spawn ssh "user@computer-B"
    expect "password:"
    send "passwd\n"
    expect "Last login:"
    send "cd tmp\n"
    send "wget $url\n"
    expect "saved"
    send "scp * user@computer-A:~/\n"
    expect {
    "yes/no" { send "yes\n"; exp_continue }
    "password:" { send "passwd\n" }
    }
    expect "100%"
    send "rm *\n"
    send "exit\n"
```

But now the script will scp the file to A immediately not until wget finishing. Is my script close to the proper way to do it? If not what should I do? Thanks very much.

Comment: You have a far better answer. The expect issue is probably that you're timing-out. Do `set timeout -1` before the wget call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `expect`, and you could use [key-based login](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Key-Based_SSH_Logins) to make your life easier.

## SOCKS

You could use a [socks proxy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Dynamic_Port_Forwarding).

From computer A :

`ssh -D 1080 address-of-B`

followed by

`export SOCKS_SERVER=127.0.0.1:1080`

You can now use `wget` from computer A.

## One liner

From computer A :

```
ssh computer-B 'wget -O - $url' >> filename_on_computer_a
```

Comment: Wow, it works. Far easier than I imaged. Thanks a lot.